# How do I delete a similar alembic version?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic

When I am trying to do

```
alembic upgrade head
```

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR [alembic.util.messaging] Online migration expected to match one row when updating '3aae6532b560' to 'a1d8dae7cc' in 'alembic_version'; 2 found
FAILED: Online migration expected to match one row when updating '3aae6532b560'
to 'a1d8dae7cc' in 'alembic_version'; 2 found
```

`alembic current`

gives two similar versions of alembic like:

```
3aae6532b560
3aae6532b560
```

How do I delete one of the similar versions of alembic, i.e a copied version?

alembic history doesn't show any messed up output.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Alembic version is stored within your database in alembic_version table. I see that you have two self same rows inside the table.

You can do something like this:

```
DELETE FROM alembic_version WHERE version_num='3aae6532b560';
INSERT INTO alembic_version VALUES ('3aae6532b560');
```

Above query could be done in one query by limiting number of deleted rows, but limiting within DELETE query is different between different databases engines.

Comment: is this still the way it works ? no command line operation ?

Comment: OK `alembic current` gives you what revision is applied to db,  `alembic history` shows all versions,  `alembic downgrade <revisionNumber>`  downgrades to a revision.  to remove head revision, downgrade and remove the file that is the head rev.